# Magento 2 - Blocking rude words in Shipping Address

Tags: magento2, input

I work for a samples based company and recently we have had a run of sample orders ordered as jokes, often with offensive names in the shipping details.

Is there a plugin or way to block offensive terms being used in input fields to deter people from placing such orders?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few plugins you can use,

- **Amasty Profanity Filter**: This plugin allows you to filter and block
  offensive words and phrases from various input fields in Magento,
  including customer names, addresses, and more.
- **Magefan Content Security**: This plugin provides various security
  features, including profanity filtering and content moderation. It
  allows you to define a list of offensive words and prevents their
  usage in different areas of your Magento store.
- **Mirasvit Content Restrictions**: This plugin offers extensive content
  restriction capabilities, including the ability to block offensive
  terms and words in input fields. It allows you to create custom rules
  for different fields, such as customer names, email addresses, or
  order comments.